# execute drawRect on every frame?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I'm trying to implement a custom view which visualizes a value which is changing in real time (like for example the volume of the audio output), and to achieve this I would like to have drawRect execute every animation frame to render the correct view state for the value.

The only solution I can think of is to set a timer to execute 60 times per second, and call `view.setNeedsDisplay()` but I'm sure this is not the best way to get this behavior and guarantee smooth performance.

**edit** to give a *slightly* more concrete example

So the situation I have is basically this:

```
//There is a variable which is changing continuously
var dynamicFoo : Double!

//I want to create a view class which renders foo in real-time
class fooVisualizerView : UIView {

   //I have drawing code which renders foo at any given value
   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
       valueDependantDrawFunction(dynamicFoo)
   }

}
```

Ideally I would like `fooVisualizerView` to redraw on every animation frame.

Comment: I suggest you research doing this as an event based system instead. Doing things based on a timer is very very bad for performance.

Comment: My value is changing faster then 60 frames per second - what I want is for my view to essentially sample the underlying value at every display frame update and render whatever value.  It's the same way an OpenGL game would handle drawing so it should be possible, but the rendering is really simple so I'd like to do it with UIKit if possible.

Comment: @sak based on that extra information I've removed the second part of my answer. CADisplayLink plus setneedsdisplay will hopefully meet your needs if the rendering is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CADisplayLink` sounds like what you want - this is effectively a timer that is called every time the screen is updated. You can call `setNeedsDisplay` from the display link method.

Note though that your code needs to complete in 1/60 of a second for this method or it will look terrible.